# call rest API in project A which is added as a jar dependency to project B

Tags: java, rest

Project 1 --->jar build
Project 2--->jar build

Project 2 has dependency of project1.

Now we just run the project 2 locally and then call the api written in Project 1.
But the hit to the API isn't happening.

Any idea what i may be missing.Googling didn't help much.

Project A has a rest api configured like this

```
 @Path("/mytest")
    public interface myApi {
    @PUT
    @Path("/create")
    void create(MyModelmodel);  
}
```

Implemented as

```
@Component
public class myApService implements myApi {


   @Autowired
   public myClient myClient;

    @Override
    public void create(MyModel model) {
        myClient.createazureworkspace(model);

    }

}
```

Added Project 1 as a dependency jar in pom of Project 2

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.xxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>project a</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now when i call http://localhost:8080/mytest/create it doesn't even hit the api
Tried adding the below code in Project 2

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages ="com.basepack.projectA")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

But it too didn't work

Comment: Show some code samples.
How you connect to REST API? Is this request logged? what are logs

Too much questions here to help you

Comment: Is the api running in a webserver? And is it available through your browser? Also make sure that you exported the project 1 in your build of the project 2

Comment: If project A provides a REST API, it should be deployed separately. Thus, Project B has a semantical, but not a syntactical dependency on A.

Comment: Code sample-->sorry cant paste

Comment: "*Code sample-->sorry cant paste*" - Then we cannot help.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54981805/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: What i can share is this is a spring boot project.Added dependency of project 1 in 2 in pom.xml.itss running in the tomcat server which is part of the spring boot project.so if i need to call API of 1 from Project 2 wat shud i do?confused in that part.

Comment: Again: No code, no help. We cannot debug what we cannot see. If you have some kind of NDA, then discuss this problem with someone who is allowed to see it.

Comment: noone is asking for delicate data - paste code changing some names, and not postig full URL's. we are not spies, but in same time we are not mindreaders

Comment: Do you have a controller implementing `myApi`?

Comment: Its a spring boot project.Yes.will add it.Its not a controller but an implementation class for the interface

Comment: The thing is i can get a hit on the API in the normal case.The only issue here is that the api is in one spring boot project that is added to another spring boot project as a jar dependency.The latter is being started up and just the api of the former is called from postman.

Comment: Is `Project1` and `Project2` and independent microservices?

Comment: Seems more like a sysadmin type question - having been through this with work stuff (Websphere 8, IBM's RBD which is a screwed up old version of eclipse, etc) recently I recall there being a spot in the Server properties/config (right click on your server) and add the appropriate project and/or JAR as an "installed application".

Comment: Project 2 is a microservice..project 1 is independant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to make it work!

1. One of the issues was a missing `@Service` over the implementation.
2. Package names were refactored.
3. The port I was calling was different from which it was getting
   started on.

Going through the startup logs helped.

Now the call to the `api` works.

Comment: what is the use of adding a jar. Are you trying to do a microservice

Comment: The project 2 is a microservice.project 1 isnt.

Comment: The reason is that project 2 only is intended to be the deployed one.the project 1 will be just its dependency.